# How to capture value from textInput() field and use it in a variable in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have an textInput() field like this.`echo Html::textInput('xxx');` I want to capture whatever the user types when he clicks the submit button and use it in a variable `$variable`. How to do this in core Yii2 style?

Comment: `$variable = Yii::$app->request->post('xxx');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is name xxx

In you controller action related  to the submitted  form

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
$your_value = $post['xxx'];
```